# Replacement of array to the number from two-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two-dimensional array and I want replace second of two-dimensional array on random number of second array

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 500
            [4] => 600
            [5] => 700
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
        )

)
```

I want get

```
 Array (
     [1] => 5 (<- random from first array)     
     [2] => 6 (<- random from second array)    
 )
```

I tried to do:

```
foreach($variables as $key => $val) {
        $variables = str_replace($val, $val[array_rand($val)], $variables);
}
```

Why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($variables as $key => $val) {
        $variables[$key] = $val[array_rand($val)];
}
```

Comment: Yes! I thinked about another function and I didnt look at this easy way :( Its happend after long work day. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($variables as &$var) {
     $var = array_rand($variables[$var]);
}
```

Comment: -1. If you are picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the `KEY` for a random entry. So you are storing keys, not values.